# Laravel Autocomplete using foreign key to show data from another table

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, autocomplete

i have created an auto complete search box in controller of 'booking' table successfully , but i want the auto complete search box to show data from another table 'patient' that have a one to many relationship with "booking" table according to a specific condition using 'where' condition ,

This is the Booking Controller that i add autocomplete in it:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Booking;
use App\Patient;
use App\User;
use Session;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Input;
class BookingController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

$search = \Request::get('search');

$bookings = Booking::whereHas('patient', function ($query) use ($search) {
     $query->where('patient_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
})->where('status','=', null)->whereHas('patient', function ($query){
  $query->where('company_id','=' ,Auth::user()->company_id); 
})->paginate(10);




         return view('booking.index')->withBookings($bookings);
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */


public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
        $query = $request->get('term','');

        $bookings=Booking::whereHas('patient', function ($query){
        $query->where('company_id','=' ,Auth::user()->company_id);

        })->$data=array();
        foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
                $data[]=array('value'=>$booking->patient->patient_name,'id'=>$booking->id);
        }
        if(count($data))
             return $data;
        else
            return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
    }
```

and this is the Booking Model :

```
class Booking extends Eloquent
{

 public function patient()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient'); 

    }

    public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
and this is the patient Model:

class Patient extends Eloquent
{
     public function booking()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Booking'); 

    }

     public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
```

and i used this code in view :

```
{!! Form::text('search_text', null, array('placeholder' => 'Search Text','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'search_text')) !!}
```

i want to show data from "patient" table and there is a one to many relationship between "booking" and "patient" table and i have successfully made a search box to search in patient table as you can see in index function , but i dont know to show data from "patient" table using where condition to show patient_name that his company_id equal Authenticated user company_id

Sorry for my Bad Language .

Comment: can you please sum up ur issue, since its hard to peel down what are u wanting to do. Are u trying to set up a search form where user can type a patient name on it, then u will get/display the bookings related to that patient right ?

Comment: i want to make autocomplete that i added in index_booking to show  patient_name  from  "patient" table and there is a relationship between  "patient" table and "booking" table ,  i mean that its easy to make autocomplete show data from "booking" table because this is the same controller and view but i need to load data from patient table , it seems to be an eager loading approximately , i dont know the syntax of code

Comment: yes @Leo_Kelmendi trying to set up a search form where user can type a patient name on it and auto complete show all patient_name from patient table according to WHERE Condition

Comment: Okay I hope I got it right: so u initialize patient model: $patient = App\Patient;    then u get patient_name that has a booking from the patient table where patient company id is equal to auth user company id. Like so   $patient_name = $patient->booking->where(Auth::user()->company_id , '=', $patient->user->company_id)->pluck('patient_name);  This is how I would look for it on tinker. Try it out. Hope it helps !

Comment: sorry , could you write the syntax please ?

Comment: U mean to write the whole thing ? Just copy paste the code I gave u modify it as needed and try it out.

Comment: same problem , Any Help Please ??